# How to use axel or aria2 for apt-get?

Tags: installation, terminal, apt-get

I have a beauty debian :P and 6Mb p/s Internet. But when I will download install a package from repo download speed is very slow (40kb p/s).

And when I will download a package from web page I download 300KB until 500KB in p/s with axel and aria2.

Can I use this tools for speedup apt-get download speed?

Comment: Is this a shared system? It sounds like bandwidth throttling may be enabled, but that usually needs to be done on purpose.

Comment: @Lemur not shared system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace your current apt-get repository by a faster mirror. See the mirror list at http://www.debian.org/mirror/list for more information

Comment: How I can recognize that which mirror is faster?

Comment: I find a package: 

`netselect-apt` . Run netselect-apt in terminal and this command search between all mirrors and find fastest mirror. Then that create a `source.list` file in home. Copy this file into `/etc/apt/` and run `sudo apt-get update` and install anythings :D